# Javascript displaying animated gifs from twitter api

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, twitter

Does anyone know of a way to make Jason Mayes Twitter Post Fetcher to include animated gifs? I have managed to pull in the gifs but they appear as jpgs and not in gif/video format...

Here is also a codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZomxM

Here is the javascript, CSS and HTML for the Post Fetcher:

```js
/*********************************************************************
*  #### Twitter Post Fetcher v18.0.3 ####
*  Coded by Jason Mayes 2015. A present to all the developers out there.
*  www.jasonmayes.com
*  Please keep this disclaimer with my code if you use it. Thanks. :-)
*  Got feedback or questions, ask here:
*  http://www.jasonmayes.com/projects/twitterApi/
*  Github: https://github.com/jasonmayes/Twitter-Post-Fetcher
*  Updates will be posted to this site.
*********************************************************************/
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    // Browser globals.
    factory();
  }
}(this, function() {
  var domNode = '';
  var maxTweets = 20;
  var parseLinks = true;
  var queue = [];
  var inProgress = false;
  var printTime = true;
  var printUser = true;
  var formatterFunction = null;
  var supportsClassName = true;
  var showRts = true;
  var customCallbackFunction = null;
  var showInteractionLinks = true;
  var showImages = true;
  var useEmoji = true;
  var targetBlank = true;
  var lang = 'en';
  var permalinks = true;
  var dataOnly = false;
  var script = null;
  var scriptAdded = false;

  function handleTweets(tweets){
    if (customCallbackFunction === null) {
      var x = tweets.length;
      var n = 0;
      var element = document.getElementById(domNode);
      var html = '<ul>';
      while(n < x) {
        html += '<li>' + tweets[n] + '</li>';
        n++;
      }
      html += '</ul>';
      element.innerHTML = html;
    } else {
      customCallbackFunction(tweets);
    }
  }

  function strip(data) {
    return data.replace(/<b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/b>/gi, function(a,s){return s;})
        .replace(/class="(?!(tco-hidden|tco-display|tco-ellipsis))+.*?"|data-query-source=".*?"|dir=".*?"|rel=".*?"/gi,
        '');
  }

  function targetLinksToNewWindow(el) {
    var links = el.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = links.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      links[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      links[i].setAttribute('rel', 'noopener');
    }
  }

  function getElementsByClassName (node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var regex = new RegExp('(^| )' + classname + '( |$)');
    var elems = node.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0, j = elems.length; i < j; i++) {
        if(regex.test(elems[i].className)){
          a.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }
    return a;
  }

  function extractImagesUrl(image_data) {
    if (image_data !== undefined && image_data.innerHTML.indexOf('data-image') >= 0) {
      var data_src = image_data.innerHTML.match(/data-image=\"([^"]+)\"/ig);
      for (var i = 0; i < data_src.length; i++) {
        data_src[i] = data_src[i].match(/data-image=\"([^"]+)\"/i)[1];
        data_src[i] = decodeURIComponent(data_src[i]) + '.jpg';
      }
      return data_src;
    }
  }
 

  var twitterFetcher = {
    fetch: function(config) {
      if (config.maxTweets === undefined) {
        config.maxTweets = 20;
      }
      if (config.enableLinks === undefined) {
        config.enableLinks = true;
      }
      if (config.showUser === undefined) {
        config.showUser = true;
      }
      if (config.showTime === undefined) {
        config.showTime = true;
      }
      if (config.dateFunction === undefined) {
        config.dateFunction = 'default';
      }
      if (config.showRetweet === undefined) {
        config.showRetweet = true;
      }
      if (config.customCallback === undefined) {
        config.customCallback = null;
      }
      if (config.showInteraction === undefined) {
        config.showInteraction = true;
      }
      if (config.showImages === undefined) {
        config.showImages = false;
      }
      if (config.useEmoji === undefined) {
        config.useEmoji = false;
      }
      if (config.linksInNewWindow === undefined) {
        config.linksInNewWindow = true;
      }
      if (config.showPermalinks === undefined) {
        config.showPermalinks = true;
      }
      if (config.dataOnly === undefined) {
        config.dataOnly = false;
      }

      if (inProgress) {
        queue.push(config);
      } else {
        inProgress = true;

        domNode = config.domId;
        maxTweets = config.maxTweets;
        parseLinks = config.enableLinks;
        printUser = config.showUser;
        printTime = config.showTime;
        showRts = config.showRetweet;
        formatterFunction = config.dateFunction;
        customCallbackFunction = config.customCallback;
        showInteractionLinks = config.showInteraction;
        showImages = config.showImages;
 useEmoji = config.useEmoji;
        targetBlank = config.linksInNewWindow;
        permalinks = config.showPermalinks;
        dataOnly = config.dataOnly;

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (script !== null) {
          head.removeChild(script);
        }
        script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        if (config.list !== undefined) {
          script.src = 'https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/list?' +
              'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false&list_slug=' +
              config.list.listSlug + '&screen_name=' + config.list.screenName +
              '&suppress_response_codes=true&lang=' + (config.lang || lang) +
              '&rnd=' + Math.random();
        } else if (config.profile !== undefined) {
          script.src = 'https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/profile?' +
              'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false' +
              '&screen_name=' + config.profile.screenName +
              '&suppress_response_codes=true&lang=' + (config.lang || lang) +
              '&rnd=' + Math.random();
        } else if (config.likes !== undefined) {
          script.src = 'https://syndication.twitter.com/timeline/likes?' +
              'callback=__twttrf.callback&dnt=false' +
              '&screen_name=' + config.likes.screenName +
              '&suppress_response_codes=true&lang=' + (config.lang || lang) +
              '&rnd=' + Math.random();
        } else {
          script.src = 'https://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/' +
              config.id + '?&lang=' + (config.lang || lang) +
              '&callback=__twttrf.callback&' +
              'suppress_response_codes=true&rnd=' + Math.random();
        }
        head.appendChild(script);
      }
    },
    callback: function(data) {
      if (data === undefined || data.body === undefined) {
        inProgress = false;

        if (queue.length > 0) {
          twitterFetcher.fetch(queue[0]);
          queue.splice(0,1);
        }
        return;
      }

      // Remove emoji and summary card images.
      if(!useEmoji){
        data.body = data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="Emoji[^>]*>)|(<img[^c]*class="u-block[^>]*>)/g, '');
      }

      // Remove display images.
      if (!showImages) {
        data.body = data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="NaturalImage-image[^>]*>|(<img[^c]*class="CroppedImage-image[^>]*>))/g, '');
      }
      // Remove avatar images.
      if (!printUser) {
        data.body = data.body.replace(/(<img[^c]*class="Avatar"[^>]*>)/g, '');
      }

      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = data.body;
      if (typeof(div.getElementsByClassName) === 'undefined') {
         supportsClassName = false;
      }

      function swapDataSrc(element) {
        var avatarImg = element.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        if (avatarImg) {
          avatarImg.src = avatarImg.getAttribute('data-src-2x');
        } else {
          var screenName = element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]
              .getAttribute('href').split('twitter.com/')[1];
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.setAttribute('src', 'https://twitter.com/' + screenName + 
              '/profile_image?size=bigger');
          element.prepend(img);
        }
        return element;
      }

      var tweets = [];
      var authors = [];
      var times = [];
      var images = [];
      var rts = [];
      var tids = [];
      var permalinksURL = [];
      var x = 0;

      if (supportsClassName) {
        var tmp = div.getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet');
        while (x < tmp.length) {
          if (tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').length > 0) {
            rts.push(true);
          } else {
            rts.push(false);
          }
          if (!rts[x] || rts[x] && showRts) {
            tweets.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-text')[0]);
            tids.push(tmp[x].getAttribute('data-tweet-id'));
            if (printUser) {
              authors.push(swapDataSrc(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-author')[0]));
            }
            times.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('dt-updated')[0]);
            permalinksURL.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-timestamp')[0]);
            if (tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-media')[0] !==
                undefined) {
              images.push(tmp[x].getElementsByClassName('timeline-Tweet-media')[0]);
            } else {
              images.push(undefined);
            }
          }
          x++;
        }
      } else {
        var tmp = getElementsByClassName(div, 'timeline-Tweet');
        while (x < tmp.length) {
          if (getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'timeline-Tweet-retweetCredit').length > 0) {
            rts.push(true);
          } else {
            rts.push(false);
          }
          if (!rts[x] || rts[x] && showRts) {
            tweets.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'timeline-Tweet-text')[0]);
            tids.push(tmp[x].getAttribute('data-tweet-id'));
            if (printUser) {
              authors.push(swapDataSrc(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x],'timeline-Tweet-author')[0]));
            }
            times.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'dt-updated')[0]);
            permalinksURL.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'timeline-Tweet-timestamp')[0]);
            if (getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'timeline-Tweet-media')[0] !== undefined) {
              images.push(getElementsByClassName(tmp[x], 'timeline-Tweet-media')[0]);
            } else {
              images.push(undefined);
            }
          }
          x++;
        }
      }

      if (tweets.length > maxTweets) {
        tweets.splice(maxTweets, (tweets.length - maxTweets));
        authors.splice(maxTweets, (authors.length - maxTweets));
        times.splice(maxTweets, (times.length - maxTweets));
        rts.splice(maxTweets, (rts.length - maxTweets));
        images.splice(maxTweets, (images.length - maxTweets));
        permalinksURL.splice(maxTweets, (permalinksURL.length - maxTweets));
      }

      var arrayTweets = [];
      var x = tweets.length;
      var n = 0;
      if (dataOnly) {
        while (n < x) {
          arrayTweets.push({
            tweet: tweets[n].innerHTML,
            author: authors[n] ? authors[n].innerHTML : 'Unknown Author',
            author_data: {
              profile_url: authors[n] ? authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:user_link"]').href : null,
              profile_image: authors[n] ? 
              'https://twitter.com/' + authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title.split('@')[1] + '/profile_image?size=bigger' : null,
              profile_image_2x: authors[n] ? 'https://twitter.com/' + authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title.split('@')[1] + '/profile_image?size=original' : null,
              screen_name: authors[n] ? authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:screen_name"]').title : null,
              name: authors[n] ? authors[n].querySelector('[data-scribe="element:name"]').title : null
            },
            time: times[n].textContent,
            timestamp: times[n].getAttribute('datetime').replace('+0000', 'Z').replace(/([\+\-])(\d\d)(\d\d)/, '$1$2:$3'),
            image: (extractImagesUrl(images[n]) ? extractImagesUrl(images[n])[0] : undefined),
            images: extractImagesUrl(images[n]),
            rt: rts[n],
            tid: tids[n],
            permalinkURL: (permalinksURL[n] === undefined) ?
                '' : permalinksURL[n].href
          });
          n++;
        }
      } else {
        while (n < x) {
          if (typeof(formatterFunction) !== 'string') {
            var datetimeText = times[n].getAttribute('datetime');
            var newDate = new Date(times[n].getAttribute('datetime')
                .replace(/-/g,'/').replace('T', ' ').split('+')[0]);
            var dateString = formatterFunction(newDate, datetimeText);
            times[n].setAttribute('aria-label', dateString);

            if (tweets[n].textContent) {
              // IE hack.
              if (supportsClassName) {
                times[n].textContent = dateString;
              } else {
                var h = document.createElement('p');
                var t = document.createTextNode(dateString);
                h.appendChild(t);
                h.setAttribute('aria-label', dateString);
                times[n] = h;
              }
            } else {
              times[n].textContent = dateString;
            }
          }
          var op = '';
          if (parseLinks) {
            if (targetBlank) {
              targetLinksToNewWindow(tweets[n]);
              if (printUser) {
                targetLinksToNewWindow(authors[n]);
              }
            }
            if (printUser) {
              op += '<div class="user">' + strip(authors[n].innerHTML) +
                  '</div>';
            }
            op += '<p class="tweet">' + strip(tweets[n].innerHTML) + '</p>';
            if (printTime) {
              if (permalinks) {
                op += '<p class="timePosted"><a href="' + permalinksURL[n] +
                   '">' + times[n].getAttribute('aria-label') + '</a></p>';
              } else {
                op += '<p class="timePosted">' +
                    times[n].getAttribute('aria-label') + '</p>';
              }
            }
          } else {
            if (tweets[n].textContent) {
              if (printUser) {
                op += '<p class="user">' + authors[n].textContent + '</p>';
              }
              op += '<p class="tweet">' +  tweets[n].textContent + '</p>';
              if (printTime) {
                op += '<p class="timePosted">' + times[n].textContent + '</p>';
              }

            } else {
              if (printUser) {
                op += '<p class="user">' + authors[n].textContent + '</p>';
              }
              op += '<p class="tweet">' +  tweets[n].textContent + '</p>';
              if (printTime) {
                op += '<p class="timePosted">' + times[n].textContent + '</p>';
              }
            }
          }
          if (showInteractionLinks) {
            op += '<p class="interact"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/' +
                'tweet?in_reply_to=' + tids[n] +
                '" class="twitter_reply_icon"' +
                (targetBlank ? ' target="_blank" rel="noopener">' : '>') +
                '</a><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?' +
                'tweet_id=' + tids[n] + '" class="twitter_retweet_icon"' +
                (targetBlank ? ' target="_blank" rel="noopener">' : '>') + '</a>' +
                '<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=' +
                tids[n] + '" class="twitter_fav_icon"' +
                (targetBlank ? ' target="_blank" rel="noopener">' : '>') + '</a></p>';
          }
          if (showImages && images[n] !== undefined && extractImagesUrl(images[n]) !== undefined) {
            var extractedImages = extractImagesUrl(images[n]);
            for (var i = 0; i < extractedImages.length; i++) {
              op += '<div class="media">' +
                    '<img src="' + extractedImages[i] +
                    '" alt="Image from tweet" />' + '</div>';
            }
          }
          if (showImages) {
            arrayTweets.push(op);
          } else if (!showImages && tweets[n].textContent.length) {
            arrayTweets.push(op);
          }

          n++;
        }
      }

      handleTweets(arrayTweets);
      inProgress = false;

      if (queue.length > 0) {
        twitterFetcher.fetch(queue[0]);
        queue.splice(0,1);
      }
    }
  };

  // It must be a global variable because it will be called by JSONP.
  window.__twttrf = twitterFetcher;
  window.twitterFetcher = twitterFetcher;
  return twitterFetcher;
}));


// Prepend polyfill for IE/Edge.
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('prepend')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'prepend', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function prepend() {
        var argArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
          docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
        
        argArr.forEach(function (argItem) {
          var isNode = argItem instanceof Node;
          docFrag.appendChild(isNode ? argItem : document.createTextNode(String(argItem)));
        });
        
        this.insertBefore(docFrag, this.firstChild);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, Document.prototype, DocumentFragment.prototype]);

/**
 * ### HOW TO CREATE A VALID ID TO USE: ###
 * Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
 * Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
 * Create a new widget for what you need eg "user time line" or "search" etc.
 * Feel free to check "exclude replies" if you don't want replies in results.
 * Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page and
 * you should see the widget you just created. Click edit.
 * Look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
 * 345735908357048478
 * Use this as your ID below instead!
 */

/**
 * How to use TwitterFetcher's fetch function:
 *
 * @function fetch(object) Fetches the Twitter content according to
 *     the parameters specified in object.
 *
 * @param object {Object} An object containing case sensitive key-value pairs
 *     of properties below.
 *
 * You may specify at minimum the following two required properties:
 *
 * @param object.id {string} The ID of the Twitter widget you wish
 *     to grab data from (see above for how to generate this number).
 * @param object.domId {string} The ID of the DOM element you want
 *     to write results to.
 *
 * You may also specify one or more of the following optional properties
 *     if you desire:
 *
 * @param object.maxTweets [int] The maximum number of tweets you want
 *     to return. Must be a number between 1 and 20. Default value is 20.
 * @param object.enableLinks [boolean] Set false if you don't want
 *     urls and hashtags to be hyperlinked.
 * @param object.showUser [boolean] Set false if you don't want user
 *     photo / name for tweet to show.
 * @param object.showTime [boolean] Set false if you don't want time of tweet
 *     to show.
 * @param object.dateFunction [function] A function you can specify
 *     to format date/time of tweet however you like. This function takes
 *     a JavaScript date as a parameter and returns a String representation
 *     of that date.
 * @param object.showRetweet [boolean] Set false if you don't want retweets
 *     to show.
 * @param object.customCallback [function] A function you can specify
 *     to call when data are ready. It also passes data to this function
 *     to manipulate them yourself before outputting. If you specify
 *     this parameter you must output data yourself!
 * @param object.showInteraction [boolean] Set false if you don't want links
 *     for reply, retweet and favourite to show.
 * @param object.showImages [boolean] Set true if you want images from tweet
 *     to show.
 * @param object.lang [string] The abbreviation of the language you want to use
 *     for Twitter phrases like "posted on" or "time ago". Default value
 *     is "en" (English).
 */

var configProfile = {
  profile: { screenName: "toongif" },
  domId: "example1",
  maxTweets: 5,
  enableLinks: true,
  showUser: true,
  showTime: true,
  showImages: true,
  lang: "en",
  showInteraction: true
};
twitterFetcher.fetch(configProfile);
```

```css
/* 
* Example style!
* You can do whatever the hell you want on your site :-)
*/

h2 {
  clear:both;
}

p, a {
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a, a:visited {
  color: #63b7e5;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
  color:#82afff;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
}
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0px 20px;
  max-width:300px;
  width: 300px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color: #417abd;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li:hover {
  /*background-color:#f0f3fb;*/
}

.user, .tweet, .timePosted {
  float:left;
}

.user {
  width:100%;
  color: #FFF;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#396aa5;
}

.user a {
  color:#FFF;
}

.tweet {
  padding:20px;
  line-height: 1.65em;
  font-size:1em;
  flex: 1;
}

.timePosted {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
 /* flex: 41;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.user a {
 width: 100px;
}

.user span span {
  display:block;
  float: left;
  width: 180px
}

.user img, .user a > span {
  float:left;
}

.user div {
 /*clear: left; */
  margin: 5px 10px 0px 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  width:180px
}

.interact {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  text-align:center;
}

.interact a {
  margin: 0px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  
}

.user a > span {
  margin-left:10px;
}

.media img {
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-height:200px;
}

#linkage {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-color:#3d3d3d;
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px;
  width:10%;
  font-family:arial;
}

.twitter_reply_icon:before{
  content:"\f075";
  display:block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
.twitter_retweet_icon:before{
  content:"\f079";
  display:block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}

.twitter_fav_icon:before{
  content:"\f004";
  display:block;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
  <head><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:600px; color:#fff; padding:50px;">
    
     <div id="example1"></div>
      
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that Twitter converts `.gif` files to `.mp4` video format so the script should be searching for them. I made a couple of small modifications to the script to look for those videos.

The parts that i changed:

```
function extractImagesUrl(image_data) {
 if (image_data !== undefined && image_data.innerHTML.indexOf('data-image') >= 0) {
   var data_src = image_data.innerHTML.match(/data-image=\"([^"]+)\"/ig);
   var type = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < data_src.length; i++) {
    data_src[i] = data_src[i].match(/data-image=\"([^"]+)\"/i)[1];
    /* Check if source has tweet_video_thumb in data-image attribute */
    if (data_src[i].includes('tweet_video_thumb')) {
      type = 'video';
      data_src[i] = decodeURIComponent(data_src[i]).slice(-15) + '.mp4';
    } else {
      type = 'image';
      data_src[i] = decodeURIComponent(data_src[i]).slice(-15) + '.jpg';
    }
  }
  /* return media object with type (either video or image) and id */
  var obj = {
    mediaType: type,
    id: data_src[0]
  }
  return obj
}
```

AND:

```
if (showImages && images[n] !== undefined && extractImagesUrl(images[n]) !== undefined) {
  var extractedImages = extractImagesUrl(images[n]);
  /* if mediaType === 'video' return video container else return image container */
  if (extractedImages.mediaType === 'video') {
    op += '<video autoplay loop class="media">' +
    '<source type="video/mp4" src="https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/' + extractedImages.id + '"/>' + '</video>';
   } else {
     op += '<img class="media" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/' + extractedImages.id + '"/>'
   }
}
```

and in css:

```
/*.media img {*/
.media video {
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  max-height:200px;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o2ygaw0/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question - would this work with videos too? Also do you know what is making the padding above and below the videos instead of being aligned to the bottom?

Comment: Okay, I managed to figure out to remove the extra padding so no worries there. Unfortunately the code you amended does not work for videos and images too, which in part was my fault as I didn't specify before. Would you be able to please point me in the direction of how to enable it for jpegs, images and video? Thinking I need some kind of if statement? Thanks again

Comment: @CodePine sorry i was a bit busy, glad you got the styling to work :) I updated parts of the code so you can pull both, images and video. Updated the fiddle too. Could have done it bit cleaner way but at least it works now :)

Comment: Ah! thankyou for showing me how to do it with an else statement. Am I right in thinking that videos are now pulling in a thumbnail? Any way to get it to autoplay/play on hover or is it not supported? Also noticed that it doesn't pull in thumbs for some videos- do you know why? Also can you explain to me what ".slice(-15)" does? Thankyou for your wonderful help and sorry about all my questions! :)

Comment: No problem :) Well to get it to autoplay/play on hover would require some additional modifications, definitely doable tho. With `.slice()` we're extracting the video/image id from the the initial string, in this case 15 last characters. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense, thanks for the link. What kind of modifications would be needed to have it autoplay? Also any idea why some videos don't show(show as a broken image icon)?

Comment: Just figured out that I think the reason why some videos show as a broken icon is because their source link to the video file is a BlobURL, so it breaks. Do you have any idea how I can either make the blobURL links work or if the link contains one, have it show the thumbnail instead?

Comment: actually could also be because on some videos the video url changes, such as 'ext_tw_video_thumb' or 'amplify_video_thumb' when trying to extract